# in openzeppelin Governance Contract, How does the contract ensure that the execution parameters are the same as those for proposal

Tags: solidity, contract-development, governance

https://github.com/PatrickAlphaC/dao-template/blob/main/contracts/governance_standard/GovernorContract.sol

in the contract, when a proposal is successful, someone can call the _execute function with parameters to execute the proposal. So how does the contract ensure that the execution parameters are the same as those for the proposal?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The `_execute` function you linked is not the actual `execute` function you would call. This is the main `execute` function: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/6aac66d065dc39795fbad1f680f80e3a3d70f2d1/contracts/governance/Governor.sol#L320

And if you take a look at it, you would see the `proposalId` is a data retrieved by hashing `execute` parameters (`targets`, `values`, `calldatas`, `descriptionHash`). And `proposalId` is used for retrieving the status of a proposal in the same function. If you send a different parameter other then the proposed one, the hashing would return a wrong `proposalId` and you would get `"Governor: proposal not successful"` which comes from the require statement from the `execute` function.